# image width to fill the page in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook

I need to write a simple document in MS Word (2007). The document must contain an image and the width of the image shoul be equal to page width (i.e. if the page width changes, the image width changes too). The document should be HTML type, hence all I need is to insert something equal to

```
<img src="image.jpg" width=100%>
```

Is it possible? And how?

Why I need it? I want to use MS Word Mail Merge in order to send several e-mail via MS Outlook, hence I have to prepare the e-mail text in MS Word first.

Comment: Sorry, but MS Word doesn't support hat sort of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, there is no built-in option available in Word for this request. If you are familiar with VBA code, you may refer to the discussion in [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/b1c0fba9-6fb9-4229-8025-e86b6644f4ff/auto-size-images-to-fit-inside-margins?forum=word) to see if the requirement can be realized using code.

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting this into the HTML source of your Word document:

```
<img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" width="100%" style="width: 100%;">
```

At least in Outlook 365 (as of 2022), this works beautifully, so I guess it should work in Word 365 just as well.

Comment: That souns interesting. But how can I do do it? I know how "unzip" the docx file and extract "source files",  but I am not familiar with the file structure. Is there some easy-to-use-tool for Linjecting"?

Comment: I just tried it. The only way seems to be to save the Word file as a web page, then open the HTML part with a text editor and, for the image in question, replace the code

**img width=xxxx height=yyyy**
by
**img width="100%"**

However, Word immediately resets the 100% image size to a fixed size as soon as you reopen the file in Word.

So the trick does not seem to work in Word. 

In Outlook, however, it works fine and, and the 100% width of the image is preserved permanently, and as well for replies and forwards, as long as the image is not copied and pasted into another message.

Comment: In Word, it might still be possible to insert the image into a table as a background, and set the table to 100% width. However, since Word does not support a background image in a table, this would also have to be inserted externally by editing the HTML source code.

Comment: If a web page is designed in Word as in the OP, then obviously it works by simply making the above change in the HTML source code of the finished web page.